# how to create a vertical sidebar menu while hovering it should display three colums of submenu?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

</span> Gift Guide</a> -->
                Paintings

Style

Fine Art

Abstract

Modern

Street Art

Pop Art

Subject

Portrait

Landscape

Still Life

Nature

Beach

Medium

Oil

Watercolor

Acrylic

Airbrush

Digital

Answer (score 0):

Use this

[Link to vertical menu](https://www.bootply.com/fe4AfcEnKD)

https://www.bootply.com/fe4AfcEnKD